# Java Regex to split a String with int, doubles

Tags: java, regex, split

I have a String that I want to split;

```
String x = "abc4.5efg2hij89k.9";
```

I want the output as

```
abc, 4.5, efg, 2, hij, 89, k, .9
```

I can easily split across digits and non digits however '.' is considered a character.

```
x.split("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)|(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)")
[abc, 4, ., 5, efg, 2, hij, 89, k., 9]
```

What is the best way of supporting doubles?

Comment: Not sure how in java but in other lang you can make your own groups with brackets like `[A-Z,a-z]` to exclude `.` from matching

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you considered letter characters instead of using the `\D` token?

```
String s = "abc4.5efg2hij89k.9";
String[] parts = s.split("(?<=[a-z])(?=[\\d.])|(?<=\\d)(?=[a-z])");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
```

Output

```
[abc, 4.5, efg, 2, hij, 89, k, .9]
```

Comment: Thanks! to match uppercase as well String[] parts = s.split("(?<=[A-Za-z])(?=[\\d.])|(?<=\\d)(?=[A-Za-z])");

Answer (score 1):

You could do matching instead of splitting and then store the matches to an array list.

```
[^\\d.]+|\\d*(?:\\.\\d+)?
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/xE1tB1/4)

```
String x = "abc4.5efg2hij89k.9";
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("[^\\d.]+|\\d*(?:\\.\\d+)?");
Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(x);
ArrayList<String> returnValue= new ArrayList<String>();
while(matcher.find())
     {
         if(matcher.group().length() != 0)
         {
             returnValue.add(matcher.group());
         }
     }
System.out.println(returnValue);
```

Output:

```
[abc, 4.5, efg, 2, hij, 89, k, .9]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=[a-zA-Z])(?=[^a-zA-Z])|(?<=[^a-zA-Z])(?=[a-zA-Z])
```

Split by this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vN3sH3/19